# Laravel Select2 returns normal select

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use select2 for my laravel Create function. but it does nothing, and i followed multiple tutorials with the same results.

index.blade(my scripts are in the header)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Subfolders</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha512-nMNlpuaDPrqlEls3IX/Q56H36qvBASwb3ipuo3MxeWbsQB1881ox0cRv7UPTgBlriqoynt35KjEwgGUeUXIPnw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js" integrity="sha512-2ImtlRlf2VVmiGZsjm9bEyhjGW4dU7B6TNwh/hx/iSByxNENtj3WVE6o/9Lj4TJeVXPi4bnOIMXFIJJAeufa0A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  @stack('page_scripts')
</head>
@include('admin.file.create')
```

here i include the 'create.blade' file

create.blade:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
    <h1 class="display-3">Add File</h1>
    <div>
      @if ($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div><br />
      @endif

      <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.file.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">{{('title')}}*</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="value">{{('Short description')}}</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description_short" />
        </div>     
       
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">{{('Tags')}}*</label>
       <select id="tag_ids" name="tag_id[]" class="form-control" multiple>
          <option value="">{{('Select Tags')}}</option>
            @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <option value=" {{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
       </div>
        
        <p>* required</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add File</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@push('page_scripts')
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tag_ids').select2();
   });

 </script>
@endpush
```

image of the select: [image]

if i need to upload any more information i will gladly do so!

Comment: Please check any error exist in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery CDN and call the select2 function. I have attached a sample code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Select2</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```